# Css animation multiple states

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I have a div animation below which translate from bottom to top repeatedly.
`0px to -20px to 0px to -20px to 0px....` but I want it to translate like this
`0px to -20px to 5px to -20px to 0px to -20px to 5px to -20px to 0px`

[The demo is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/vzhen/tj23tcmj/)

HTML

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="example"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#example{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-animation: example 0.5s linear 0s infinite alternate;   
}

@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {transform:translate(0px,0px);}
    to {transform:translate(0px,-20px);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all change the syntax of the animation from to and from to percentage based I.E.

from ::

```
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    to {transform:translate(0px,0px);}
    from {transform:translate(0px,-20px);}
}
```

to ::

```
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0% {transform:translate(0px,0px);}
    50% {transform:translate(0px,-20px);}
    100% {transform:translate(0px,5px);}
}
```

now see with percentages , you can animate an element at any point , **DEMO** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yxq41nsc/)

Answer (score 1):

use percertanges instead of from and to.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tj23tcmj/2/)**

```
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0% {transform:translate(0px,-20px);}
    25% {transform:translate(5px,-20px);}
    50% {transform:translate(0px,-20px);}
    75% {transform:translate(5px,-20px);}
    100% {transform:translate(0px,0px);}
}
```

I don't if this is the desired effect. Just update accordingly.